# Porting Promise Chaining from AngularJs to VueJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, promise, es6-promise

Similar to my last question but different enough that I am at a loss. I have the following function in AngularJs that I need to recreate in VueJs. I have two similar ways I've tried to write this in VueJs, but they are causing lots of site exceptions both ways.

AngularJs

```
var foo = function(obj, config) {
    if (config.skip) {
        return $q.reject("Skipping");
    }
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    obj.promise = deferred.promise;
    if (obj.hasValue()) {
        deferred.resolve(obj);
    } else {
        "/api/callToApi".$promise.then(function(res) {
            if (res) {
                deferred.resolve(res);
            else {
                deferred.reject(res);
            }
         });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

VueJs - take 1. I'm pretty sure this one is missing the actual promise chaining, not sure how to correctly set that.

```
var foo = function(obj, config) {
    let returnEarly = false;
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        returnEarly = true;
        reject("Skipping"):
    }
    if (returnEarly) {
        return promise;
    }
    obj.promise = promise;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (obj.hasValue()) {
            resolve(obj);
        } else {
            axios.get("/api/callToApi").then(function(res) {
                if (res) {
                    resolve(res);
                } else {
                    reject(res);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console errors with take 1

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at XMLHttpRequest.__capture__.onreadystatechange
```

VueJs - take 2. I thought this way would return the correct chaining, but I get an error `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout` when running jest tests.

```
var foo = function(obj, config) {
    let returnEarly = false;
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        returnEarly = true;
        reject("Skipping"):
    }
    if (returnEarly) {
        return promise;
    }
    obj.promise = promise;
    return promise.then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (obj.hasValue()) {
                resolve(obj);
            } else {
                axios.get("/api/callToApi").then(function(res) {
                    if (res) {
                        resolve(res);
                    } else {
                        reject(res);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is plain JavaScript, not specific to Vue.

It's generally unnecessary to assign a promise to `obj.promise` because it's returned from the function.

Excessive use of `new Promise` is known as promise constructor antipattern. If there's already a promise (Axios returns one), there's no need to create a new one, this results in redundant and error-prone code (this can be the reason for `Async callback was not invoked...` error). In case a new promise needs to be created, there are shortcut `Promise` methods.

Should be something like:

```
function(obj, config) {
    if (config.skip) {
        return Promise.reject("Skipping");
    }

    if (obj.hasValue()) {
        return Promise.resolve(obj);
    } else {
        return axios("/api/callToApi").then(function(res) {
            if (res)
                return res;
            else 
                throw res;
            }
         });
    }
}
```

It's a bad practice in general to make errors anything but `Error` object.

Also notice that Axios response object is always truthy, possibly needs to be `res.data`.

Will be more concise when written as `async..await`.

Comment: Thanks again Estus for the help! I have learned a lot about promise anti-patterns. Thanks again